# Get all elements with given prefix but namespace declared locally

Tags: xml, xpath

I have some XML files using many different prefixes. Most of the **namespaces are declared locally, but not in the root element**. I need an XPath expression to get all elements with the specific prefix `terms`.

```
   <root>
    <wrapper xmlns:terms="http://terms.example.com">
      <terms:trid>somevalue</terms:trid>
      <terms:identifier>someID-</terms:identifier>
      <foo:bar>somevalue</foo:bar>
    </wrapper>
   </root>
```

I tried `//terms:*` and get the following error:

> XPath failed due to: Prefix terms has not been declared

Is there a way that I can get these elements without declaring the namespace in the root element of the original files?

Comment: Is a code solution an option? This isn't too hard to script.

Comment: @Sobrique What would you have this script do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespace prefixes themselves have no meaning in XML. They are always used in conjunction with a namespace URI - in a *namespace declaration*. Even if there are ways to access the prefixes:

```
 substring-before(name(/root/wrapper/*[1]),":")
```

which would return

```
terms
```

you should never rely on prefixes when writing XPath expressions. They would be exceptionally brittle, since prefixes are assumed not to carry any meaning and thus could be changed without changing the semantics of the document.

Probably, you are really trying to access elements associated with a particular namespace URI, regardless of the (arbitrary) prefix. This is one of several ways to do it:

```
//*[namespace-uri() = "terms.example.com"]
```

and the result will be (individual results separated by `-------`):

```
<terms:trid>somevalue</terms:trid>
-----------------------
<terms:identifier>someID-</terms:identifier>
```

However, the most appropriate way to deal with namespaces is to make this namespace URI available to your XPath engine, assign it a prefix and prefix element names in your path expressions.

Comment: Note though, that it's a bad idea to use a relative URI like `terms.example.com` for a namespace name. It means that the elements all have different names if downloaded from e.g. `http://www.example.com/somepath/something.xml` where they are then in the namespace `http://www.example.com/somepath/terms.example.com` or `C:\Users/Someone\Downloads\something.xml` where they are in the namespace `file:///c|Users/Someone/Downloads/terms.example.com`. Use a full URI reference like `http://terms.example.com/`

Comment: @JonHanna Perhaps you meant to ping yram about this? I suspect that `terms.example.com` was ... an example. Also, since namespace URIs are arbitrary strings that are not dereferenced, it seems odd to me that they should somehow be extended to the left, depending on the location of the document. Do you have any proof to substantiate this claim? Thanks.

Comment: @JonHanna Nevermind, I found everything I need [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#NSNameComparison) and [here](http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xppa#47802880).

Comment: Thanks, both. @JonHanna, even though I meant it as an example, it is good to have this sort of clarification as part of the thread. I have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: @yram it can be unclear sometimes when an example is just an example, and when it's an example of something that can cause problems.